# How do I add duplicate rows to a data frame in R?

Tags: r

I currently have an edge list in R that looks something like this:

```
From  To   Start      End 
A     B    1/1/2011   1/2/2011
A     F    1/1/2011   1/1/2011
B     G    1/2/2011   1/2/2011 
C     A    1/2/2011   1/6/2011
D     C    1/2/2011   1/3/2011
```

What I would like to do is create a new edge list in R that looks something like this

```
From  To   Time
A     B    1/1/2011
A     B    1/2/2011
A     F    1/1/2011
B     G    1/2/2011
C     A    1/2/2011
C     A    1/3/2011
C     A    1/4/2011
C     A    1/5/2011
C     A    1/6/2011
D     C    1/2/2011
D     C    1/3/2011
```

In other words, I would like to duplicate the first two columns each row in the first table for each day between the start and end date, inclusive. What would be a good way to do this? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Where's the data coming from? Are you making it up?

Comment: The data here is just an example I made up; the actual file is much too large to include here

Comment: You can always include a sample of your data, e.g., with `dput(head(df))`. You should also update your question based on your comment to the first answer, since what you want is not well-explained in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Date` class has a `seq` function (`seq.Date`) that you can use, or you can use `IDate` from `data.table`:

```
df = read.table(text = 'From  To   Start      End 
A     B    1/1/2011   1/2/2011
A     F    1/1/2011   1/1/2011
B     G    1/2/2011   1/2/2011 
C     A    1/2/2011   1/6/2011
D     C    1/2/2011   1/3/2011', header = T)

library(data.table)
dt = data.table(df)

dt[, cbind(.SD, seq(as.Date(Start, '%m/%d/%Y'),
                as.Date(End, '%m/%d/%Y'), 1)), by = list(Start,End)]

# or
dt[, cbind(.SD, seq(as.IDate(Start, '%m/%d/%Y'),
                    as.IDate(End, '%m/%d/%Y'), 1)), by = list(Start,End)]
#       Start      End From To         V2
# 1: 1/1/2011 1/2/2011    A  B 2011-01-01
# 2: 1/1/2011 1/2/2011    A  B 2011-01-02
# 3: 1/1/2011 1/1/2011    A  F 2011-01-01
# 4: 1/2/2011 1/2/2011    B  G 2011-01-02
# 5: 1/2/2011 1/6/2011    C  A 2011-01-02
# 6: 1/2/2011 1/6/2011    C  A 2011-01-03
# 7: 1/2/2011 1/6/2011    C  A 2011-01-04
# 8: 1/2/2011 1/6/2011    C  A 2011-01-05
# 9: 1/2/2011 1/6/2011    C  A 2011-01-06
#10: 1/2/2011 1/3/2011    D  C 2011-01-02
#11: 1/2/2011 1/3/2011    D  C 2011-01-03
```

Comment: to avoid using `.SD`, use something like `dt[,list(Time = seq(from = as.Date(Start,format = '%m/%d/%Y'),to= as.Date(End,format = '%m/%d/%Y'),by = 'day' )),by='From,To']`

Comment: @mnel: Thanks so much! On my actual data I am getting an error stating that "from must be of length 1" when I use the code you posted above. Would you know why I might be getting such an error? Sorry for not posting actual data online - I am not allowed to share it

Comment: @eddi Thank you! This works perfectly on the sample data, but when I apply to the actual data I get this error "Error in data.table(..., key = key(..1)) : 
  argument 2 (nrow 2) cannot be recycled without remainder to match longest nrow (3)" Would you know why this error might be popping up? Thanks so much!

Comment: @overflowname you have duplicate `Start`/`End`'s, try doing a "by" by all columns (you won't need to `cbind` `.SD` in that case, for same reason as @mnel's answer): `dt[, seq(as.IDate(Start, '%m/%d/%Y'), as.IDate(End, '%m/%d/%Y'), 1), by = list(From, To, Start, End)]` - if you still get that error that means you have duplicate lines in your data and should filter those out.